# save_pretrained function with fine tuned bert model with cnn

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

```
class MixModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='bert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__() 
        config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
        self.bert =  BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',config=config)
        self.hidden_size = self.bert.config.hidden_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=3072, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size= 64- 5 + 1)
       
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.flat=nn.Flatten()
        self.clf1 = nn.Linear(256,256)
        self.clf2= nn.Linear(256,6)
          
           
    def forward(self,inputs, mask , labels):

        inputs=torch.tensor(inputs)
        mask=torch.tensor(mask)
        labels=torch.tensor(labels)
        
        x = self.bert(input_ids=inputs,attention_mask=mask, return_dict= True) 
 
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.clf1(x)
        x = self.clf2(x)
        
        return x
```

I want to save model,weights and config file for my model after training. after searching I found that model.save_pretrained function is good solution for me but I got an error that model called mixmodel has no function called save_pretrained
so how can I save config file for my model mixmodel?

Comment: Following the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73948214/7631183 solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think that "state_dict" is what you need.

There's good tutorial for PyTorch in the documentation
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay but save_dict do not save the config file